# C# Get Substring from STring using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a log from a firewall, which is in what I think is a horrible format, but the information I actually want to extract is relatively consistently delimited. An Example (although I've removed all the specific information for privacy) would be:

```
<46>Nov7 04:33:25 FirewallDeviceName [Some identifier from the firewall, can contain spaces]: in:[InterfaceName] out:[InterfaceName], connection-state:new src-mac [Mac-ID], proto UDP, [SourceIP]:[SourcePort]->[Dst-IP]:[Dst-Port], len 32
```

What I want to extract from this is just the Source and Destination IP Addresses and ports, and maybe also the In and Out interfaces, and maybe the protocol.

I thought that the best way to do this would be to use a combination of .SubString(pos,length) and .IndexOf(char) with RegEx to match the bits of the string that I need for each.

For Example:

- \s[0-9]+\. would get the part of the string where the source-IP starts.
- [0-9]+\, would get the end of the section containing the IP-Addresses
- Can Split() this first using "-->" to split the source and destination and then split each of these using ":" to separate the IP Address from the Port.

The bit I don't know is how to use RegEx within either the IndexOf (to get the character position) or within SubString functions, or even if that's possible.

Any help or advice here.

What I'm basically looking to write initially is a parser to parse some text-file logs that I've generated (these were generated from a syslog listener that I wrote for our new firewall, to work out what the output looked like)... ultimately the parser will be built into the listener itself so that the bits I want are logged directly to an SQL Database, but that bit I can do... it's the parser with the Regex that I'm not sure about.

Thanks very much.

Comment: If you match the whole line against a Regex, using capture groups for the bits you want, you can just get the values of those capture groups. No need for manually fetching substrings etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example text given, the RegEx

```
, (\[SourceIP\]:\[SourcePort\])->(\[Dst-IP\]:\[Dst-Port\]),
```

will capture the source and destination into `$1` and `$2`. However, I suspect that they are actually numbers with dots and not words within square brackets. Thus a better expression may be

```
, ([\d.]+:\d+)->([\d.]+:\d+),
```

This RegEx matches the two parts within `proto UDP, 1.2.3.4:567->8.9.0:123, len 32`.